# Post request using axios fails with "Response for preflight is invalid" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, axios

I made the following post request to a 3rd party api, from my web frontend, using axios, but it couldn't go through.

```
  Axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://some.website.com/oauth/token',
    data: {
     client_secret: 'revmisodtoire43-00j232onfkdl',
     code: '54728349765905473289',
     grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('client info: ', res);
  });
```

The error says:`Failed to load https://some.website.com/oauth/token: Response for preflight is invalid`, and then `network error`.

When I made the same request via curl, it went through with no problem.

I know this is CORS related, but am not sure what to do with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing much you can do, if you are using 3rd party api. API provider should support AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether content-type is being added in the header's, if not try adding this 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' in the request headers

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but that should be part of the response headers sent by the server of the api provider. There's no use to send it from the client making the request.

Comment: It should be part of your request headers, because you are making a request which is outside of your domain, so you need to make a CORS request.